# Can't make GAE Channel API work on local computer

Tags: python, ajax, json, google-app-engine, channel

I am creating a small application to test how GAE Channel API works. I think I have done all as it's described in the documentation but when I launch it, it shows an error in FireFox error log about syntax in the beginning and then another repeating error that an element wasn't found that.
Here is the first error info:

```
Source: http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/channel/dev?command=connect&channel=channel-773698929-185804764220139124118
Line 1, symbol 1
```

Here is the url where my javascript code tries to connect repeatedly and it raises the second error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/channel/dev?command=poll&channel=channel-2071442473-185804764220139124118&client=1
```

I get the token through a JSON request with jQuery `$.get`. Then I run this code to get the token and open the channel. The error begins to show just when I run `socket = channel.open(handler)`:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
        var token = response.token.toString();
        channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
        var handler = {
            'onopen': onOpened,
            'onmessage': onMessage,
            'onerror': function() {
            },
            'onclose': function() {
            }
        };

        socket = channel.open(handler);
```

Here is the server side code in Python to open the channel:

```
class OpenChannel(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        token = channel.create_channel(user.user_id())
        serialized = json.dumps({'token': token})
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
        self.response.out.write(serialized)
```

What's my error and what can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Channel API works on localhost different way than on GAE hosting. I uploaded it to the cloud and it works well now. Though it looks like it working fine on the local computer, it shows permanent JS error repeating in the error log.

Comment: this should be part of your question or a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I think so, but anyway seems like not many people faced the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the handler argument and adding the handlers as methods of the socket object i.e. `socket.onopen = function() {};` etc. That worked for me. But you are right. According to [this](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/javascript.html), you should be able to get this working by using the handler argument. Hmm.